# Mayer-Vietoris sequence in simplical homology for a $\Delta$-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Hatcher's Exercise 2.2.37 asks as follows:

**Exercise 2.2.37.** Give an elementary derivation for the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in simplical homology for a $\Delta$-complex $X$ decomposed as the union of subcomplexes $A$ and $B$.

I don't understand what this question exactly means. It seems like we can derive the M-V sequences in the special case for $\Delta$-complexes more easily than the general case, but I have no idea. How can I derive the M-V seq. for $\Delta$-complexes in an elementary way?

Comment: "elementary" is up to interpretation, but in the case that you have an actual $\Delta$-complex, you can formulate the MV sequence using just the second isomorphism theorem. the point is just that you can avoid some of the uglier details you have with singular homology, but its probably still not a one-line proof

Comment: @pancini are you able to expand a bit on why the second isomorphism theorem can be used for the $\Delta$-complex case and not for the singular case?

Comment: @Anon I'm not sure what exactly I meant at the time, but the $\Delta$-complex case presumably involves chain complexes with finitely generated (or at least countably generated) modules in each dimension. The singular chain complex is a bit outlandish since in nearly any case there are uncountably many generators of every dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it might help to consider that this is *not* about a "special case" of the Mayer-Vietoris of singular homology. It is instead the *Mayer-Vietoris sequence of simplicial homology*.

You are being asked to figure out what "the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in simplicial homology" actually means, so you need to define the terms and the arrows of that sequence, and combine those appropriately to form a "Mayer-Vietoris sequence".

Having done that, your job is then to prove that the sequence you have written down is exact.

Regarding the meaning, the idea is simple: for each subcomplex $Y \subset X$, restrict the $\Delta$-complex structure on $X$ to obtain a $\Delta$-complex structure of $Y$, use that to define the simplicial chain complex $\Delta_n(Y)$, and use that to define its simplicial homology groups $H_n(X)$; also, use the inclusion $Y \subset X$ to define the chain maps $\Delta_n(Y) \to \Delta_n(X)$, and use that to define the induced homology homomorphisms $H_n(Y) \mapsto H_n(X)$.

Now apply this to three subcomplexes: $Y=A$; $Y=B$; and $Y=A \cap B$. Once that's done, you've pretty much defined all the terms and all the arrows of the following sequence, subject to throwing in appropriate $\pm$ signs for the maps defining the arrows:
$$\cdots \mapsto H_n(A \cap B) \mapsto H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \mapsto H_n(X) \mapsto H_{n-1}(A \cap B) \mapsto\cdots
$$
and now prove that this sequence is exact.

Comment: Would we then be able to change $C_n(A+B)$ to $\Delta_n(A\cup B)$ in the short-exact sequence of chain complexes? Or is the potential overlap between the $\Delta$-complexes in $A$ and $B$ rendering it not a valid $\Delta$-complex structure? Otherwise, what makes this question interesting? It seems the same as in the singular case...